# "that I continue to learn and grow", does this expression sound natural?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

One of my friends was asked the next-5-year-play in a job interview. He answered this way

> I don’t know exactly, but the most important thing is **that I continue to learn and grow**
>   in my career.

Does this answer sound natural? Would it convey some kind of determination or plan?

Comment: The sentence begins with "I don't know exactly," which means the speaker has **no plan**, and which is confimed by the vague statement that they want to improve, so there is not much **determination** either. So no, it's just [**waffle**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/waffle) and is unlikely to get the job.

Comment: Contrast with (edit as appropriate): "Yes, I am aiming to secure further promotion within your company, with the intention of becoming a manager, and believe I have the ability and committment to be running my own department within 5 years. That way, I can also secure the best education for my children, who I intend to put through college eventually."

Comment: @WeatherVane  Thanks a lot!  The other part of my OP, does the expression itself, "that I continue to learn and grow", sound natural?

Comment: IMO the use of "grow" in relation to working life is becoming a cliché. Anyway, a "five-year plan" would have some definite goals, not be answered by a vague feel-good expression. The learning and growth will be a natural consequence of the very real determination expressed in a plan, not ends in themselves. The sentence comes over a bit like "therapy group".

Comment: @WeatherVane  Thanks a lot! Btw, does "therapy group" refer to "a form of psychosocial treatment" or some kind of metaphor?

Comment: Not a metaphor ... or [encounter group](https://psychology.jrank.org/pages/217/Encounter-Group.html).